# How to pass array of Union in c

Tags: c

I have the following data types declaration.

```
    typedef struct{
            int aa;
    }A;

    typedef struct{
        int bb;
    }B;

    typedef struct{

        union {
                A a;
                B b;
        }*D;

        int other;
    }myType;

    //Now I want to pass the array "D" and the variable "other" to a function 
    // that will use them to construct "myType"
    // How can I pass D as parameter? what whill be its type?

    //I want to have a function like the following with "?" filled. 

        callFunction(? d, int other){
            //construct "myType"
            myType typ;
            typ.D     = d;
            typ.other = other; 
        }
```

I have tried to declare the **union** outside the **"mytype" struct**, and then use **D* d;** in **"mytype" struct**
in that case I am having this error

error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘D’

The code is as follows:
        //struct A and B are declared above

```
    union {
            A a;
            B b;
    }D;

    typedef struct{            
            D* d;            
            int other;
    }myType;
```

Any help will be appreciable,

thanks.

Comment: Show the alternate code that gave you the error.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, I have edited my question

Comment: in your updated code all you need to do is to add `typedef` before `union` to make it work. This will make `D` a name for the anonymous union described above.

Comment: @hankol Please mark as answer answers that you find helpful (click on the green `v` to accept them). This way people will be aware that your problem is already solved, and it might also help others in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef union {
   A a;
   B b;
} D;

typedef struct{
   D d;
   int other;
}myType;

callFunction(D *d, int other)
```

or

```
union D {
   A a;
   B b;
};

typedef struct{
   union D d;
   int other;
}myType;

callFunction(union D *d, int other)
```

The body of `callFunction` will be the same for both:

```
{
            //construct "myType"
            myType typ;
            typ.D     = *d;
            typ.other = other; 
}
```